# curl ifconfig.me and ifconfig showing different results

Tags: macos, networking, curl, ifconfig

If I run `curl ifconfig.me`  I get one IP and if I run `ifconfig`, I get other IP's. Why is it so ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ifconfig` is grabbing your local, NAT'd IP address.  `curl ifconfig.me` is grabbing the public IP provided to you by your ISP.